# Change colour of vertices after they are uploaded using a VBO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

**EDIT: Working coded example by Apple found at this link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html**

After creating the vertices for a fixed grid of 200 x 200 squares, I render it by sending the vertices to the GPU using a VBO. How can I then update the colour of the vertices? The colour of hundreds of vertices will change frequently - every few frames.

I previously tackled the problem not using a VBO. I created arrays of vertices and colours and used the following code to render the vertices. I changed the colour of vertices by updating  the array `triangleColours`:

```
-(void)render {

    glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [effect prepareToDraw];

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2,
                          GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleVertices);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4,
                          GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleColours);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numTriangleVertices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
}
```

Although the above code worked, it ate a lot of battery, so now I'm trying to do it with VBOs. The vertices don't change position, so I understand that VBOs are a good choice to use, but what about changing the colour of the vertices?

This is my current code simplified to draw only a single square:

**EDIT:** How would I update the code below so it uploads only the vertex colours when they change? How should the VBO setup code and the draw code change?
How about updating my verticesColours colours array then calling glBufferSubData()?

```
    // Setup vertices and VBO

    // Vertices for a single square

    const Vertex Vertices[] = {

        // position and colour
        {{-20, -20}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
        {{-20, -20}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
        {{-20, -20}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
        {{-20, -20}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
    };

    const GLubyte Indices[] = {

        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
    };

    numIndices = sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]);

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-50.0, 50.0,
                                                                 -50.0, 50.0,
                                                                  0.0, 1.0);


    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);        
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);


// Render

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];    

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);   
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends.  (Great word, isn't it?  Good for all situations.)

If you truly need to mutate the colors of each vertex in unpredictable ways, every time you draw them, then yes you will need to upload the vertex colors each frame.  Putting the vertex positions in their own (static) VBO is a good choice, since that allows you to reuse without uploading every time (system memory <-> GPU memory bandwidth always being a precious commodity), but anything that will *have* to change, well, will *have* to change.

If you can calculate the color of each vertex programmatically, though, this is where [vertex shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader)  come in handy.  (Indeed, what they were made for!)  Hopefully, the color of each vertex is some function of some combination of:

1. Static per-vertex data.  You can upload this once in a [VBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO#Vertex_Buffer_Object) and reuse.
2. Variable data that is global across the entire array.  You use [shader uniforms](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29) for this, and just upload them once for every draw.
3. Perhaps [vertex textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Texture_Fetch), if your platform supports that?

Then, you can write a vertex shader that computes the color from those inputs, and every frame you'll only have to respecify the shader uniforms -- which is usually on the order of a dozen or so floats, total.

So it depends on how you want your colors to change.  If you can use a vertex shader, then you can indeed skip out on uploading with every draw.  If you can't and/or the mutation is too complicated or arbitrary to do in a vertex shader -- you'll just have to do that CPU-side, and  bite the upload bullet.

Comment: Never heard of _vertex textures_; texture fetch in vertex program? Seems to have been added to SM3.

Comment: Personally, I will go for vertex textures. To do texture lookups in vertex shaders you should use `texture2DLod()`. Please refer to section  *8.7 Texture Lookup Functions* of GLSL ES 2.0 specs: http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf

Comment: Say I don't use shaders and reupload colours each frame. Do I have to upload the whole grid's colour array, or I can send only the vertex colours that changed?

Comment: But maybe I can use a shader. Each cell in the grid can be in one of 2 states: on and off (black and white). I maintain these states in an array. A cell is on if 2 or 3 of its neighbouring cells are on, otherwise it is off. Can this logic be processed in a shader?

Comment: @dene: you'd have to reupload the entire color array; no picking and choosing.  Your particular logic will be hard to encapsulate in a shader, though, since invocations of the shader are independent and do not share information.  Perhaps post another question for that?

Comment: @sheu Considering the approach you mention, using a shader to set vertex colors. How about if the vertex shader had a uniform color array of the possible colors, and an attribute colorIndex. Is it possible to set colorIndex outside the shader as and when a specific vertex needs to change color?