# How to update VBO vertex data directly?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have a vertex buffer and an index buffer to render a polygon mesh.
I would like to manipulate the position of N number of vertices (move them around independent of other neighboring vertices).

How can i go about doing this?

And i certainly hope I dont have to go back to using glDrawArrays (instead of glDrawElements). It took me forever just to figure out the vertex/index buffer rendering.

Comment: I was able to find a similar question. It helps, but i'd like to get a confirmation on this with the community. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574660/change-colour-of-vertices-after-they-are-uploaded-using-a-vbo?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get slightly better performance if you update the data using glBufferSubData, specially if you can avoid updating all the buffer but just an small part of it. Unless you move your vertex animation into the vertex shader, you need to update the vertex buffer each time a vertex is moved (by your user), and glBuffer(Sub)Data is your best bet.

EDIT: Create the VBO as DYNAMIC, and if you make changes very often, create two buffer and use a double buffering approach, to avoid a performance hit since this way you can write data while the gpu is using the other buffer for rendering.